# for any $x>0$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, whenever $a^T x \leq 1$, we have $b^T x \leq 1$; does this imply $a \leq b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, logic, vectors

given $a>0$, $a$ is fixed, $a,b,x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, for any $x>0$, if whenever $a^T x \leq 1$ we have $b^T x \leq 1$, then is it true that $a \geq b$?

Comment: How do you define $a\leq b$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @uniquesolution component-wise

Comment: I think you also have to assume $b>0$.

Comment: Hint: If not $a \geq b$, then find a coordinate at which $a$ is smaller than $b$, and build an $x$ that exploits this inequality to achieve $a^T x \leq 1$ but not $b^T x \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

It actually implies $a \geq b.$ We can take a limit of vectors  $x$ with all positive components, approaching
$$  \left( \frac{1}{a_1},0,0, \ldots,0  \right) $$
where $a_1 > 0.$

But then $$ \frac{b_1}{a_1} \leq 1, $$ with $a_1$ positive
$$ b_1 \leq a_1.$$ It is possible to have $b_1$ negative or $0$

Same for each $b_i$

Comment: Yes! I made a typo in the question. Should imply $b \leq a$